# Question about Dirichlet boundary problem (ODE)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

I have a question about the problem

$$y''(x) - \omega y(x)=0$$

with $y(a) = A$ and $y(b) = B$.

My approach to this problem was to just solve the ODE, so that I get

$$y(x) = C_1 \sin(\omega x) + C_2 \cos(\omega x)$$

and then I solve the problem for the boundary values by means of solving the corresponding linear system.

Is this the right way to solve such kind of a problem or did I miss something?

Comment: I thought it would be $y=C_1\sin(\omega x)+C_2\cos(\omega x)$

Comment: @Qurultay yeah you are right, thanks

Comment: You''ll want to look more closely. At some point your solution will involve $\sqrt{\vert\omega\vert}$, maybe $\sinh$ instead of $\sin$ depending on the situation, etc.

Comment: You (probably) missed the square on $\omega^2$ in the ODE itself. Otherwise it depends on the sign of $\omega$, and will involve square roots.